# Almost complete oriented graph in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to illustrate properties of binary relation on a graph **G**(*V*,*E*), where *V*={a,b,c,d,e} and E={aa,ab,ac,bb,bc,bd…}

Going through documentation and examples I tried several different approaches, however none of results was exactly satisfactory. Most elegant attempt is probably this one, yet it still does not produce complete solution:

```
\tikz \graph [simple] {
    subgraph K_n [->,n=5, clockwise];
    % Redirect edges:
    1 <- 4;
    1 <- 5;
    2 <- 5;
    2 <- 1;
    3 <- 1;
    3 <- 2;
    4 <- 2;
    4 <- 3;
    5 <- 3;
    5 <- 4;
};
```

Can I

- rename vertices to a,b,c,d,e,
- add loop to each node to illustrate reflexivity?

---

Another almost working attempt producing badly skewed graph:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm,gnode/.style={circle,draw,font=\bfseries}]
    \node[gnode](d) {d};
    \node[gnode](c) [right of=d] {c};
    \node[gnode](e) [above left of=d] {e};
    \node[gnode](b) [above right of=c] {b};
    \node[gnode](a) [above right of=e] {a};
    \graph{
        (a) -> {(b),(c)};
        (b) -> {(c),(d)};
        (c) -> {(d),(e)};
        (d) -> {(e),(a)};
        (e) -> {(a),(b)};
        };
    \path
        (a) edge [loop above] node {} (a)
        (b) edge [loop right] node {} (b)
        (c) edge [loop below] node {} (c)
        (d) edge [loop below] node {} (d)
        (e) edge [loop left] node {} (e);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: What do you mean by **almost complete**? It is complete right?

Comment: @Symbol1 binary relation *R* it is describing is defined like this: a*R*a, a*R*b, a*R*c, b*R*b, b*R*c, b*R*d, c*R*c, c*R*d, c*R*e … e*R*e, e*R*a, e*R*b. This *R* relation is represented by oriented edge in the graph, so it looks like K₅ with oriented edges and loop added at each vertex.

Comment: Oops, I got it. Well, there is `\foreach` in Ti*k*Z. And there is `1/a`-syntax so that `1` becomes the name and `a` becomes the label.

Comment: @Symbol1: Indeed! This produces acceptable graph:

`\foreach \name/\angle/\text in {P-1/234/d, P-2/162/e, P-3/90/a, P-4/18/b, P-5/-54/c}
    \node[vertex,xshift=6cm,yshift=.5cm] (\name) at (\angle:1cm) {$\text$};

\foreach \from/\to in {1/2,2/3,3/4,4/5,5/1,1/3,2/4,3/5,4/1,5/2}
    { \draw (P-\from) -- (P-\to); }

\foreach \from/\pos in {1/below,2/left,3/above,4/right,5/below}
  { \path (P-\from) edge[loop \pos] node {} (P-\from); }`

Comment: You can/are encourages to answer your own question. You can also include a snapshot to make it more beginner-friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by Symbol1’s comment I went through graphs in [Ti*k*Z gallery](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/graphs/) where the Automata example provided almost complete solution. Below is slightly tweaked code and resulting graph.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->]
    \tikzstyle{vertex}=[circle,draw=black!25,minimum size=17pt,inner sep=0pt]

    \foreach \name/\angle/\text in {P-1/234/d, P-2/162/e, P-3/90/a, P-4/18/b, P-5/-54/c}
        \node[vertex,xshift=6cm,yshift=.5cm] (\name) at (\angle:1cm) {$\text$};

    \foreach \from/\to in {1/2,2/3,3/4,4/5,5/1,1/3,2/4,3/5,4/1,5/2}
        { \draw (P-\from) -- (P-\to); }

    \foreach \from/\pos in {1/below,2/left,3/above,4/right,5/below}
        { \path (P-\from) edge[loop \pos] node {} (P-\from); }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: relation represented as graph]